# GCPのストレージ課金のタイミングはいつですか？

Tags: google-cloud

GCPのノードを利用しています。料金明細を見たところ、ノードの使用時間に対する課金はされていたのですが、ストレージの明細がありませんでした。ストレージの課金額は月単位で計算されると思うのですが、明細に反映されるのは月末になるのでしょうか？

また、GB単位でストレージの金額が設定されていたとして、1GB未満の金額はどのように計算されるでしょうか(切り捨てですか?明細に反映されていないのは、切り捨てだからでしょうか)。

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage のドキュメントに記載があります: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

> 料金は毎日発生しますが、Cloud Storage から請求が行われるのは請求期間の終了時のみです。未請求の使用量は、Google Cloud Console の[プロジェクトのお支払いページ](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/settings?_ga=2.10549364.1799314661.1595486398-1550903996.1595486398)で確認できます。

また、Cloud Storage には無料枠もありますので、そこからはみ出さない限りは請求が発生しません。